# How to allow method in C# web service to retrieve data from website?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

This is my restful web service code.And I tried to get some data from web site.But in there is an error occurred.It says "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed " What I can do to prevent this.

```
    namespace WebService1
    {
       [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
       [WebService(Namespace = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
       [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
       [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
       public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService 
       {
            public Service1()
            {
            }

            [WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
            public string sayHelloJson(string name)
            {
                string strgreeting = string.Format("Hello {0}", name);
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return js.Serialize(strgreeting);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my html code.I run it using wamp server..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Greeting(){

         var Name=$('#txtname').val();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:54884/Service1.asmx?op=ssayHelloJson',
            //data: ({ name : 'ggg' }),
            dataType: "html",
             contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(data) {
                // Run the code here that needs
                //    to access the data returned
                alert( data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    }

    </script>


</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" >
    <div>
        <p>json format call</p>
        Enter name:<input type="text" id="txtname" />
        <input type="button" id="btngo" value="GO" onclick="Greeting()" />


    </div>
    <p id="result"></p>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When exactly are you getting this error message? How are you **calling** this service? Just browsing to an URL with a browser, or calling it some other way (which way?)?

Comment: I used a html file. And I run it through Wamp server.

Comment: Can you **show us** that HTML please?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function Greeting(){

     var Name=$('#txtname').val();
    
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:54884/Service1.asmx?op=ssayHelloJson',
        data: ({ name : 'ggg' }),
        dataType: "html",
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function(data) {
            // Run the code here that needs
            //    to access the data returned
            alert( data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}

</script>

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Um extreamly sorry. becoz I m new to stack overflow..

Comment: change url to `            url: 'http://localhost:54884/Service1.asmx/ssayHelloJson',
`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function Greeting(){

         var Name=$('#txtname').val();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
//your method name in webservice change like this 
            url: 'http://localhost:54884/Service1.asmx/ssayHelloJson',
           data: ({ name : 'ggg' }),
            dataType: "POST",
             contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(data) {
                // Run the code here that needs
                //    to access the data returned
                alert( data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
```

And ur web config add service get and post request

```
<location path="Service1.asmx">
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</location>
```